# how to change ng-options to be ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm beginner AngularJS developer, and I'm building simple app but I have a problem

This is my Html

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="TabsDemoCtrl">
    <div ng-controller="TabsDemoCtrl">      
      <label>Category</label>
      <select class="form-control" ng-model="product.category" ng-options="category as category.name for category in categories"></select>    
    </div>

    <label>how to change ng-options to be ng-repeat ?my achieve is to be like this</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="custom">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="non-custom">
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is my Js

```
angular.module('MyApp', [
    'ui.bootstrap']);

(function(MyApp) {
  'use strict';
  MyApp.controller('TabsDemoCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    // categories
    $scope.categories = [
      {
        name:'custom', 
        templateAttribute: [
          {attribute: 'material'},
          {attribute: 'soles'},
          {attribute: 'size'}
        ]
      },
      {
        name:'non-custom', 
        templateAttribute: [
          {attribute: 'material'},
          {attribute: 'soles'},
          {attribute: 'size'}
        ]
      }
    ];     
  }]);
})(angular.module('MyApp'));
```

this is my simple [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QypYGO)

How to output data on ng-option to be repeat form text? Thank advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
<div ng-repeat="category in categories">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="category.name">
</div>
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjWMRR)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I am new to Angular as well, but this has worked for me the last few days.

```
<div ng-controller="TabsDemoCtrl">      
    <label>Category</label>
    <select class="form-control" > 
        <option ng-repeat="category in categories">{{category.name}}</option> 
    </select>    
</div>
```

Comment: why you need `ng-repeat` though you have `ngOptions` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. this may help you

```
<select ng-options="catagory.name as catagory.name for catagory in categories" ng-model="categoryName"class="form-control" name="categoryName">  
<option value="">Select Category</option>
</select>
```